# Error when trying to update photo metadata using Street View Publish Service Client - Python

Tags: python, google-maps, google-cloud-platform, google-street-view, google-streetview-publish

I have uploaded a couple of photos in Street View and I want to use the Python client library to update its metadata. Find below a snippet of my code:

```
from google.proto.streetview.publish.v1 import resources_pb2
from google.streetview.publish.v1 import street_view_publish_service_client as client
from google.protobuf import field_mask_pb2

streetview_client = client.StreetViewPublishServiceClient(credentials=credentials)

for photo in streetview_client.list_photos(0, ''):
    con = resources_pb2.Connection()
    target_id = resources_pb2.PhotoId()
    target_id.id = "photo_id"
    con.target.id = target_id.id
    photo.connections.extend([con])
    update_mask = field_mask_pb2.FieldMask()
    update_mask.FromJsonString("connections")
    response = streetview_client.update_photo(photo, update_mask)
    break
```

I want to connect both photos so I add the target id to the query photo and the field "connections" to the update_mask.
The result after the `update_photo` call is the following error message:

> google.gax.errors.RetryError: RetryError(Exception occurred in retry
>   method that was not classified as transient, caused by <_Rendezvous of
>   RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, Empty level
>   name is not accepted.)>)

Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

In order to do a connections between two photos, you need to use [`Method: photos.batchUpdate`](https://developers.google.com/streetview/publish/reference/rest/v1/photos/batchUpdate). `Connections` should be set right under `Photo`. Also, be noted of the metadata of the [`Photo`](https://developers.google.com/streetview/publish/reference/rest/v1/photo) that you need to implement.

Here's a sample code snippet.

```
pose = resources_pb2.Pose(level=resources_pb2.Level(name="lvl", number=0))
connection1 = resources_pb2.Connection(target=resources_pb2.PhotoId(id="idOfConnection1"))
photo = resources_pb2.Photo(connections=[connection1], pose=pose)
```